# Find unit vector

Tags: physics

Two vectors are given by

$$\vec{a} = 3.0\,\hat{i} − 2.5\,\hat{j} + 1.0 \,\hat{k}$$
and
$$\vec{b}  = −1.0\,\hat{i} + 1.0\,\hat{j} + 6.0\,\hat{k} $$

In unit-vector notation, find the following.

(a)    $\vec{a}+\vec{b} =$

(b)   $ \vec{a} − \vec{b} =$

(c)    $\vec{c}$ such that $\vec{a}-\vec{b}+\vec{c} = 0$

How is this supposed to be solved? For a, I tried adding the columns, for $4i$, $2.5j$, $49k$, then squaring everything, and then root-squaring that. It says the answer is wrong, though.

Comment: Do you know the definition of addition for vectors?

Comment: Not the definition. Was I supposed to just add without any squaring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we add two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ simply summing the coefficients of the same unit vector of the basis.

So, in your case:

$$
\vec a + \vec b = (3\,\hat{i} − 2.5\,\hat{j} + 1 \,\hat{k})+(−1\,\hat{i} + 1\,\hat{j} + 6\,\hat{k})=(3-1)\hat{i}+(-2.5+1)\hat{j}+(1+6)\hat{k}
$$
 You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction), and use this to solve also the other questions.